# How to I make Icon intersecting with v-app-component. Vuetify

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetifyjs3

[The locket is not intersecting with the v-app-bar. How can I achiev that?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l64GU.png)

```html
<template>
  <v-app-bar :elevation="2" rounded>
    <v-row class="z-index">
      <v-col cols="12" class="d-flex flex-column justify-center align-center">
        <v-app-bar-title>Login</v-app-bar-title>
        <v-icon class="position-fixed pt-14" icon="mdi-lock"></v-icon>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-app-bar>
</template>
```

Comment: overflow-visable is the answer

Answer (score 0):

this could be a possible solution, as severin mentioned you could use `overflow-viasable`:

```
<template>
 <v-app-bar :elevation="2" rounded style="overflow: visible; width: 100%;">
    <v-row class="z-index">
      <v-col cols="12" class="d-flex flex-column justify-center align-center">
        <v-app-bar-title>Login</v-app-bar-title>
        <v-icon class="position-fixed pt-11 z-index" style="z-index: 1000;" icon="mdi-lock"></v-icon>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
 </v-app-bar>
</template>
```

I also reduced margin top of the icon to make it fit inside the bar